# Improve website performance in WordPress by hosting images on a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hey I want to load my images in subdomain. **For Example: xyz.com subdomain will be images.xyz.com**.
when i post any image on my main domain the image will be stored on my subdomain.Can anyone guide me i can do it on wordpress so that my website respond fast.

Comment: It’s not clear how you reached the conclusion that by storing your images on a separate subdomain, the performance of your site would be positively impacted. Such an arrangement is not at all directly tied to performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins like [Offload Media](https://wordpress.org/plugins/offload-media-cloud-storage/) and [WP Offload Media Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) that facilitate this functionality.

Comment: is there any option without plugin

Comment: Yeah (the plugins themselves are only code), but a lot of work that the plugins have already done for you. Trying not to use plugins is great, but when dealing with this level of functionality usually better to use them.